# How do I get a CSS animation to stop after it has looped once through the CSS keyframes?

Tags: css, css-animations, keyframe

I am trying to get a zoom out effect that runs once using CSS animation and keyframes. However, the zoom keeps looping and does not stop. How can I get it to just loop through once?

```
    header {
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
    height: calc(100vh - 40px);
    position: static;
    overflow: hidden;
    background: url("../uploads/header-image.jpg");
    background-size:100%;
    background-position: center center;
    animation: imagezoom 8s forwards;
}

@keyframes imagezoom {
  0%, 100% {
    background-size: 110% auto;
    -webkit-background-size: 110%;
  }
  50% {
    background-size: 100% auto;
    -webkit-background-size: 100%;
  }
}
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation-iteration-count

Comment: I set the animation-iteration-count as 1 and changed 'infinite' to 'forward'  but this didn't work.

Comment: please provide with  html code

Answer (score 3):

add following code to your css for one iteration

```
animation-iteration-count: 1
```